# std::move and std::shared_ptr argument passed by value

Tags: c++, move, shared-ptr, move-semantics

Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Test
{
    public:
    Test(int t) : t(t) {}
    
    int t;
};

void test(std::shared_ptr<Test> t)
{
    std::cout << t.use_count() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto t = std::make_shared<Test>(1);
    test(std::move(t)); //(1)
    test(std::make_shared<Test>(2)); //(2)
}
```

Questions:

1. What ctor is executed in case (1) - copy or move?
2. In case (2) temporary is created, then copy ctor is executed to create `t` in `void test(std::shared_ptr<Test> t)`, then temporary is destroyed. Is that correct?

Comment: both cases use the move constructor (though it may be elided in the second case): https://godbolt.org/z/bf1ohrvxW

Comment: It's important to note that the movement (in both cases) and the temporary (in case 2) is the `std::shared_ptr<Test>` object itself, not the `Test` object it wraps a pointer to. There will only be one single `Test` object in each  case, which isn't moved or copied.

Comment: Confirm 1 by checking `t`'s `use_count` at the end of main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a total of 3 `std::shared_ptr<Test>` created in your example:

1. `auto t = std::make_shared<Test>(1);`
2. `test(std::move(t));` - The receiving `t` in `test()` is *move-constructed*.
3. `test(std::make_shared<Test>(2));` - The receiving `t` *is* the one created by `make_shared()`. It's the same object because of mandatory *copy/move-elision* since C++17.

   Prior to C++17, you could in theory get as many as 5 instantiations - but since this kind of elision was *allowed* (but not mandatory) in the previous version, you'll most probably only get 3 in those versions too. When using one of those earlier versions you can turn off this optimization in some compilers (`g++`/`clang++` for example) with `-fno-elide-constructors`. In C++17 and later, the elision is mandatory and can therefore not be turned off.

---

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/h84YWxdWv) which doesn't use `shared_ptr` but a test class called `foo` so that that you can track each instantiation. Note how there is only one `foo` with the value `2`, which corresponds to your `test(std::make_shared<Test>(2));` call.

Comment: Do you mean that if `-fno-elide-constructors` is used with, for example, C++11 compiler, then in case (2) in my example the receiving `t` will be created with move ctor?

Comment: @cppdev Yes ([example where gcc has `no-elide-constructors` and clang doesn't](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7sodYedY)) and note how `auto t = std::make_shared<Test>(1);` (`auto t = make_foo(1);`) also results in a move construction when that option is used, so there are 5 instances in total.